# Reading a File line by line and assigning the value to a variable in a loop

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a text file whose content is like below.

```
CAT,DOG
SPARROW,PIGEON
RAT,BAT
TENNIS,FOOTBALL
```

Further, I have a shell script that reads this text file line by line assigns value to a variable and performs certain statements.

For Example:

1st line is: CAT,DOG

variable1: CAT
variable2: DOG

Print variable1
print variable2

then code goes to 2nd line,
2nd line is: SPARROW,PIGEON

variable1: SPARROW
variable2: PIGEON

Print variable1
print variable2

And its goes on until the EOF.

Please help me to build code for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: No one is going to write the entire code for you. You should show at least some effort. What did you try?

Comment: Why not just `awk -F, '{print "v1: " $1 "  v2: " $2}' yourfile`?

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: The reason why I am using shell loop to process text file because I have written spool command to get the data output in comma separated text file.

Comment: Why does this require you to write the program in bash?

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
while IFS=, read -r var1 var2; do 
  printf 'variable1: %-10s variable2: %s\n' "$var1" "$var2"
done < file.txt
```

If you want var1 and var2 to persists/exists outside of the loop then, use an array.

```
var1=()
var2=()

while IFS=, read -r column1 colum2; do 
    var1+=("$column1") var2+=("$column2")
    printf 'variable1: %-10s variable2: %s\n' "$colum1" "$column2"
done < file.txt
```

Outside of the loop `${var1[@]}` and `${var2[@]}` arrays persists/exists

`-10` is just for pretty indentation, The values are saved in `$var1` and `$var2`

Comment: The code posted by Jetchisel is completely reasonable. "didn't work" is a useless comment, because we don't know in what way it does not work. Publish the exact code which you tried in a readable (i.e. [properly formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)) way, and explain how exactly you invoke your script, what output you get.